# Jquery Data table Particular Column Search is not working - Search value is not passing to server

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables, datatables-1.10

Project - CodeIgnitor - Datatable Ajax Pagination is working good.But custom search is not working.
i have tried to print the values passed to the server .'I am getting search
column - Search-value and Search-regex getting as empty.Please help me to resole this issue

Here is my java script code,

```
var oTable2 = $('#product_master_table').DataTable({
    
    "paginationType":"full_numbers",        
    "paginate": true,
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'serverMethod': 'post',
    "filter": true,
    'ajax': ajax_url,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "searching":true,
     dom: "ltip"
    
});
```

If i search using this,
//right now searching only 3 column

```
oTable2.columns(3).search(searchTerm,true,false );
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] for this?